# WPF install : creating and saving database location

Tags: database, wpf, installation, inno-setup

I have a WPF C# app which I have created which uses an Access Database (accdb).

I am using Inno for an installer.

I currently have a static path the database in my app.config connectionString section, however what I need is to:

- run INNO
- ask if this is the Master
  YES: install the DB file in C:/MyApp
  NO: do not install the DB file, but messageBox asking for the database location (BROWSE and verify Name) - as they will have to look on network.

This browse location answer would then replace the C:/MyApp with //192.168.1.2/C/MyApp for example in the AppConfig connection string section...

Does that sound reasonable or possible (or even 'correct' to do?)

I'm new to C# and this is my first install/deploy I've done so I am very fresh on this.

The other option I was looking at would be to ask to install the database.
If they say NO then just carry on with install.
When the wpf starts up and cant locate the database then I can code in a browse feature in the app which then writes to the appconfig file.

Which is the more Correct way to proceed or is there another option which I am oblivious to which is how it should be done?

Comment: I am not quite sure what are you are wanting to install... should the Access database for single user and not share the information between them - if so then why not to use Sqlite ? Regardless, personally I think that application needs to install everything out of package and not rely on "browse" option

Comment: too many things the user needs to do here (which also means handling more user related errors). I'd rather just ask the user where to install a database with a message like "dont worry, you can change your database in the settings later". Install the database ALWAYS, and let the user select his own database in a settings view or something. The max freedom I'd give the user is to select where to save the new database (in case he doesnt want it to be C:) but regardless, it'll still be installed - even if not used.

Comment: @Bandook actually that was the advice I was after :P
Demon, Thanks for the advice, i will be proceeding with installing all and handling via the app.

 Martin, thanks for the feedback, it was more of an intent to understand correct protocol, which has pretty much been suggested by Bandook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from correctness, one advantage to picking the DB location in the app is if the location ever changes. If you do it in the installer, they would have to reinstall.

I would probably go with installing the app as "master" by default, but also provide an option for the user to change this. Then the installer is simplified and doesn't really have to contain any application logic.